# Javascript calls blocked by other calls in firebreath

Tags: javascript, c++, boost, firebreath

Im building a plugin with firebreath, where Im trying to call two functions at the same time, multiple times using callback. But when i do the function within the plugin fires but the javascript calls fires after all the multiple plugin function calls, which is must to late.

These are the calls i need to fire synchronously:

```
 FBLOG_INFO("drawCalibration()", "Fire Calibration = (" + boost::lexical_cast<std::string>(xPos) + "," + boost::lexical_cast<std::string>(yPos) + ")");
_tracker->addCalibrationPointAsync(point, boost::bind(&TobiiWrapper::pointCompleted, this)); 
_parent->fireAsyncEvent("oncalibration", FB::variant_list_of(xPos)(yPos));
```

The "pointCompleted" basically only calls this function:

```
void TobiiWrapper::startNextOrFinish() {
if(m_calibrationPoints.size() > 0) {
    Point2d point = m_calibrationPoints.front();
    m_calibrationPoints.pop();
    boost::thread t(boost::bind(&TobiiWrapper::drawCalibrationPoint, this, point, callback));
    boost::this_thread::sleep(boost::posix_time::milliseconds(CALIBRATION_POINT_INTERVAL));
 } else {
    _tracker->computeCalibrationAsync(boost::bind(&TobiiWrapper::computeCompleted,this,_1));
 }
}
```

The callback in thread t was just an attempt to be able use the InvokeAsync function. What I've tried was using

```
callback->InvokeAsync("oncalibration", FB::variant_list_of(xPos)(yPos));
```

but this just crashes with this error "shared_ptr Assertion px != 0 failed"

How can i call addCalibrationPoint and the javascript function "oncalibration" synchronously?

Comment: I really can't tell what you're doing from your code.  I'll offer a few hints, though: 1) if you have a sleep, that *must* not be on the main thread.  2) If you're trying to call something synchronously, use callback->Invoke, not callback->InvokeAsync, otherwise it will invoke... asynchronously, which means not right away.

Comment: would _parent->fire_calibration(xPos, yPos); fire syncronously?

Comment: sorry... the first lines are code are from my "drawCalibrationPoint" function. and those calls i want to fire synchronously. Which is my problem.